# Identifying inconsistent row values in a Pandas dataframe (ignoring missing values)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which I am trying to identify cases where data is not equal across rows, ignoring missing vales.

So in the example, I want to create a new column of data where only the first row of data would be flagged, because Cell 1 and Cell 2 are not equal.  In all other rows the values are the same (excluding missing values).

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 1 |  | Cell 2 |
| Cell 4 |  | Cell 4 | Cell 4 |
| Cell 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 1 |
| Cell 8 | Cell 8 | Cell 8 |  |

I tried nunique but it treats missing data as 0 so I still can't flag cases where data, if it exists, is not equal.

It seems so simple but I can't find a solution.  Would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas` version 2.1.1, `NaN` are ignored by default using [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html). See the `dropna` argument for more details.

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd


s = """Column A Column B    Column C    Column D
Cell 1  Cell 1      Cell 2
Cell 4      Cell 4  Cell 4
Cell 1  Cell 1  Cell 1  Cell 1
Cell 8  Cell 8  Cell 8  """

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\t')

out = df.assign(flagged=df.nunique(axis="columns").gt(1))
print(out)
```

```py
  Column A Column B Column C Column D  flagged
0   Cell 1   Cell 1      NaN   Cell 2     True
1   Cell 4      NaN   Cell 4   Cell 4    False
2   Cell 1   Cell 1   Cell 1   Cell 1    False
3   Cell 8   Cell 8   Cell 8      NaN    False
```

## Resources

- [`pandas.DataFrame.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html)

Comment: very concise, I like it :) the `.gt` is a bit of a pain to me personally, `>=` is easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

```
data["Flag"] = data.apply(lambda x: len(set([i for i in x if pd.notna(i)])) == 1,axis=1)
```

It isn't as easy to understand but it does the job.

Reading it from inside out

1. First we collect all values if they are not null in a list comprehension
2. we transform it into a set => unique values only
3. We see if the length == 1 => True else False (*can be changed based on desired output*)

```
  Column A Column B Column C Column D   Flag
0   Cell 1   Cell 1      NaN   Cell 2  False
1   Cell 4      NaN   Cell 4   Cell 4   True
2   Cell 1   Cell 1   Cell 1   Cell 1   True
3   Cell 8   Cell 8   Cell 8      NaN   True
```